# package.JSON file Incomplete?

Tags: json, node.js, gruntjs

I have installed npm and grunt. In the command line, I have navigated to my project's directory, and, initiated a `package.json` file.  My problem is, it seems to only generate part of the file. It definetely generates the package.json file, but it only asks for name and version and irrespective of what I put it first presents this:

```
npm ERR! code EINVALIDTAGNAME
npm ERR! Invalid tag name "Grunt Js": Tags may not have any characters that enco
deURIComponent encodes.
About to write to C:\Users\t.steiner\Desktop\Lynda Training\Grunt Js\package.jso
n:

{
  "name": "",
  "version": ""
}


Is this ok? (yes)
```

and then this:

```
Is this ok? (yes) yes
npm ERR! Callback called more than once.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\t.steiner\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2017-11-30T13_58
_26_759Z-debug.log

C:\Users\t.steiner\Desktop\Lynda Training\Grunt Js>
```

Have I messed up the instillation of either of these items?

Comment: What command did you use to create the package.json ?

Comment: @Weedoze  npm init.  I didn't include the -y because I wanted to get the feel for the elements of the .json file

Comment: Is it immateriality after npm init? The reason I ask is because I suspect the name you entered (or that was suggested by default) is probelmatic

Comment: @Weedoze that first npm error block I put above comes up immediately.  It doesn't even give me the opportunity to enter a name or version lol

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this issue fits quite well :

https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/17830

Comment: You were right.  I closed the gaps in my file path as a test and everything worked out perfectly.

Comment: Nice !  I'm glad I could help you :)